# Non-Nullable value type issue when LEFT JOIN in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am going to work on a WinForms project which requires to use **Linq**, but I know nothing about it, so I just started learning.

After reading a tutorial about Linq I created the `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` using the `SqlMetal` tool which comes with the Microsoft Windows SDK. The database Im using as example is **"Northwind"**.

I have been able to make simple queries as following:

```
Northwind db = new Northwind("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");

var query = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID 
            select new
            {
                Customer_ID = c.CustomerID,
                Customer_Name = c.ContactName,
                Order_ID = o.OrderID
            };
```

And then I show the results in a `DataGridView` and everithing goes well.

But right now I am facing a problem which I havent been able to solve.

I tried to modify the previous query in order to make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so what I did was the following:

```
    var query = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into j
            from or in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Customer_ID = c.CustomerID,
                Customer_Name = c.ContactName,
                Order_ID = or.OrderID
            };
```

But, when I try to show these set of data in a `DataGridView` an error is raised:

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.
```

I know this problem is caused by the "Customers" that dont have a "Order", so the system tries to asign a `null` value to a `int` variable.

But then, **How can I make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` without having this error?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not convert the type to a string.  Simple cast it to the equivalent nullable type:

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into j1
            from or in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Customer_ID = c.CustomerID,
                Customer_Name = c.ContactName,
                Order_ID = (int?)or.OrderID
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the answer:

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
            join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into j1
            from or in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Customer_ID = c.CustomerID,
                Customer_Name = c.ContactName,
                Order_ID = or.OrderID == null ? "[null]" : or.OrderID.ToString()
            };
```

but Id appreciate if someone has a better answer